# Using variables declared in main within blocks

Tags: c++

I am experimenting with an online compiler, but I keep getting errors when I try to run the below program, stating that the variables were not declared in scope. I am declaring them in `main()` and then using them in a loop, and I don't understand why this error is occurring. I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding the issue and how to fix it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 
    sum = 0;
    value = 0;
    
    while(value > -1){
        sum += value;
        cout << "Enter a value" << endl;
        cin >> value;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read [some good books on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/8484779) if you're new to this programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a strongly-typed language, and requires every variable to be declared with its type before its first use

You are never declaring the variables `value` and `sum` in your entire program before using it.

**Fix**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 
    int sum = 0;
    int value = 0;
    
    while(value > -1){
        sum += value;
        cout << "Enter a value" << endl;
        cin >> value;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to [declare the variable](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_variables.asp) the right way in C++, which is:

```
<variable_type> <variable_name> = <variable_value>;
```

Also, `#include using namespace std;` is a typo, it should be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Your code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int value = 0;

    while(value > -1)
    {
        sum += value;
        cout << "Enter a value" << endl;
        cin >> value;
    }
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a value
5
Enter a value
7
Enter a value
-1
12
```

Also, see [why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).